# Lua and c++ errors windows

Tags: c++, lua

Hey I'm trying to load a Lua file into my c++ project but there are some errors I don't know how to fix... I have downloaded the libraries from Lua and I've got them in my include folder. The dll's are in my project and the libs are on the lib folder of my compiler so it shouldn't be a linker error.

The errors I'm getting are:

```
error: 'luaL_newstate' was not declared in this scope
error: 'luaL_openlibs' was not declared in this scope
error: 'luaL_dofile' was not declared in this scope
```

I have no idea what to do. I'm using codeblocks and I'm using this linker argument: `-llua5.1`

Here is my code:

```
lua_State *L = lua_open();
luaL_openlibs(L);

luaL_dofile(L,"ModificarViento.lua");

lua_getglobal(L,"MueveFlecha");

lua_call(L,0,2);

vientoX = (int)lua_tointeger(L,-2);
vientoX = (int)lua_tointeger(L,-1);
lua_pop(L,1);

lua_close(L);
```

and here are my includes of Lua

```
extern "C"{
    #include <lua.h>
    #include <lualib.h>
    #include <lauxlib.h>
}
```

If anyone knows what's wrong, please tell me.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Those are compiler errors, not linker errors. It seems like you're not including lauxlib.h, but you are. Can you show all of your code, rather than two sections of it?

Comment: As a hint for the future: please use decent English spelling, and avoid stuff like lolz, plz, etc. Aside of being a pleasure to read, it'll get you more answers to your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it. I downloaded Lua for mingw32. I had the VC++ version. Oh well